# Why do Mersenne numbers work?

Tags: prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

In Matt Parker's book: "Things to make and do in the fourth dimension", he says that mathematicians have long known that for $2^n - 1$, if $n$ is not prime then the number cannot be prime. I don't understand how this works? $2^4-1=15$, and $4$ is not prime? $2^6-1=63$ and $63$ is not prime?

Can someone explain why we use Mersenne numbers? Is there some rule that I don't know about that it only works for numbers of a certain size? Why doesn't it work for the examples I just listed?

Edit: My brain stopped working and I forgot to check math. I was originally told by a family member that $2^4-1=31$ but I only just realized that indeed, it is $15$. And I forgot that $15$'s not prime lol. Also forgot $63$ ain't prime. Thanks for everyone's responses.

Comment: What's wrong with your examples? $15$ and $63$ are not prime, so nothing is wrong here.

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly gets you stuck. Indeed $4$ is not prime, but also $2^4-1=15$ is also not prime. That's exactly what the books says, so there should be nothing confusing about that.

Comment: Yes. I just realised that. My brain is not working well this early in the morning. Originally someone tried to disprove it to me when I told them saying $2^4-1=31$ but I literally only just realised that's not true. Oopsie.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $2^{ab}-1$ is divisible by $2^a-1$ (and $2^b-1$).

Comment: To me, the more interesting conjecture, which may well be false, is the converse.  Suppose that $(2^n - 1)$ is not prime.  Does this imply that $n$ is not prime?

Comment: To expand what metamorphy says, perhaps you are familiar with the fact that
$$
a^n - b^n~\text{is divisible by }~a-b
$$
Now, if we have a number like $N=2^{rs}-1 = 2^{rs}-1^{rs}$, we can just set $a=2^r$ and $b=1^r=1$. Then the result is that $N$ is divisible by $2^s-1$. Proof completed.

Comment: @user2661923: Consider $n=11$.

Comment: Mersenne numbers are interesting because they biject with even perfect numbers and are easier to test for primality than other numbers of similar size, and in particular always include the largest known prime.

Comment: @J.G. So far the largest known prime was always a Mersenne prime , whether this will be so forever is not clear. Other numbers , like the generalized Fermat numbers , could also lead at some time to a new record prime. But since the Mersenne primes attract far more interest, this scenario is quite unlikely. Very good comment that summarizes excellent why Mersenne numbers are so special.

Comment: Weird title , but apparently such titles increase the popularity of a book ...

Comment: Mersenne primes do dominate, but from August 1989 to March 1992 the largest known prime was not a Mersenne prime: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/by_year.html#graph1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things:

- $2^{n+1}-1=2(2^n-1)+1\land 1=2^1-1\implies 2^{n+m}-1=2^m(2^n-2)+(2^m-1)$
- $n\mid 2^{n-1}-1 \implies 2^n-1=2kn+1$ , which is guaranteed for $n>2$ if $n$ is prime.
- We know that if the prime has remainder $3$ on division by $4$, and twice it plus $1$ is prime, then it won't form a prime as an exponent.

They are mostly curios, but they do coincide with even perfect numbers.  There are other things we can say, but aren't nearly as helpful.